# How to get element in array Swift IOS

Tags: arrays, swift

How can i get an array of Id from dataInfo when name or title is empty

My code

```
struct Data {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let tilte: String
}

var dataID =  [String]()

let dataInfo = [ Data(id: "1", name: "", tilte: ""), Data(id: 2, name: "K", tilte: "A"), Data(id: 3, name: "", tilte: ""), Data(id: 4, name: "4", tilte: "")]
```

my expectations

```
dataID = [1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Your *expectations* don’t match the declared type `[String]`.

Comment: What about trying something yourself first, like using a simple `for` loop for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, because of your data Info not map with your sturct.

Your data should look like this

```swift
let dataInfo = [ Data(id: "1", name: "", tilte: ""), Data(id: "2", name: "K", tilte: "A"), Data(id: "3", name: "", tilte: ""), Data(id: "4", name: "4", tilte: "")]
```

And for your question, it can divide into 2 step: Make a dataInfo when name or title is empty and get their id

Code will be like this

```swift
var dataID: [String]

let dataInfo = [ Data(id: "1", name: "", tilte: ""), Data(id: "2", name: "K", tilte: "A"), Data(id: "3", name: "", tilte: ""), Data(id: "4", name: "4", tilte: "")]

let dataInfoFilterEmpty = dataInfo.filter{($0.name.isEmpty || $0.tilte.isEmpty)}
dataID = dataInfoFilterEmpty.map{$0.id} // ["1", "3", "4"]
```

Comment: Please don't suggest `== ""`. There is `.isEmpty`

Comment: Dear @vadian, thank you for your suggestion. I have refactored it.